# Does the AzureSearch query key change if the indexer is reset or query parameters changed?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, access-keys

I am planning to use AzureSearch, and have the exposed API get invoked from a client application. I expect that the indexer and fields returned from Azure Search, to change over time.

I wanted to check if the Azuresearch API access key might change- and what steps we need to take to ensure that this is static?

This is critical, as distributing any new key to client devices could be challenging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Search indexers won't change query keys, even if you reset it. The only API that can remove query keys is [Query Keys - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchmanagement/querykeys/delete)